# Nginx as forward proxy for secure LDAP

Tags: nginx, ssl, proxy

I need help building a forward proxy for secure LDAP.

A client connects to a TCP proxy and request must be redirected to a secure LDAP at TCP 636.

```
[client]------->[localhost:636 Nginx-proxy]----TLS---->[db.debian.org:636 secure LDAP]
```

I try to build it with Nginx.

However TLS connection does not work properly.

Looks like there is a mess with certificate on the `localhost`. What certificate should be used for TLS proxy on the `localhost`?

What if Nginx is running in a container in Kubernetes? What if it is exposed as a service at `*.svc.custer.local`?

The `ldapsearch` access log of working proxy at `ldaps://localhost`

```bash
ldapsearch -x -b "dc=org" -H ldaps://localhost -v -d8
ldap_initialize( ldaps://localhost:636/??base )
TLS: hostname (LAPTOP-I14D4GNQ.) does not match common name in certificate (db.debian.org).
TLS: can't connect: (unknown error code).
ldap_sasl_bind(SIMPLE): Can't contact LDAP server (-1)
```

LDAPS-request works with ignore the certificate on the server:

```bash
LDAPTLS_REQCERT=never  ldapsearch -x -b "dc=org" -H ldaps://localhost -v -d8
ldap_initialize( ldaps://localhost:636/??base )
filter: (objectclass=*)
requesting: All userApplication attributes
# extended LDIF
#
# LDAPv3
```

Here is my Nginx config

```
worker_processes  auto;

error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log notice;
pid        /tmp/nginx.pid;

events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}

http {
    include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

    sendfile        on;
    #tcp_nopush     on;

    keepalive_timeout  65;

    #gzip  on;
    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;

    server {
        listen       8080;
        location / {
            root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
            index  index.html;
        }
    }
}

stream {
    server {
        listen     636;
        proxy_pass db.debian.org:636;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For nginx you must configure a `stream` block which terminates the SSL/TLS connection from the client -- using a cert trusted by the client for the hostname the client uses, see below -- and originates a new SSL/TLS connection to the upstream server, something like:

```
stream { 
        server {
                listen 0.0.0.0:636 ssl;
                listen [::]:636 ssl; # not actually needed since I ended up using IPv4 addressing, see below
                ssl_certificate /home/dthomps/certs/loc3bcert3.pem;
                ssl_certificate_key /home/dthomps/certs/srvx.pem; # or appended to above
                proxy_pass db.debian.org:636;
                proxy_ssl on;
                #proxy_ssl_name if necessary
                proxy_ssl_verify on;
                proxy_ssl_verify_depth 9; # should be plenty
                proxy_ssl_trusted_certificate /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt;
        }
}
```

On my (Ubuntu) system, `/etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt` is the default PEM-format truststore of 'standard' CAs which includes the CA (currently?) used by db.debian.org which is LetsEncrypt aka ISRG. It can also include local modifications made with `update-ca-certificates`; see below.

Getting the client (ldapsearch) to trust the cert used by nginx is a different matter. You can't get a cert for either the name `localhost` or a private/reserved address like `127.0.0.1` from any standard CA. If you are in an organization which runs its own (in-house) CA for its intranet, and sets up its systems to trust that CA, they *might* be able to issue such. Otherwise you must create your *own* 'DIY' CA, issue a cert to nginx, AND make that CA trusted by the client; in my case due to previous work I already have such a CA set up and trusted (see `update-ca-certificates` above). Even so, with the `ldapsearch` version I have (`ldap-utils 2.4.45+dfsg-1ubuntu1.11`), I couldn't get it to trust a (valid) cert for `localhost` (and it didn't give me a detailed error like yours did, only "Can't contact LDAP Server (-1)"), but it worked using 127.0.0.1 in both the cert and the URL:

```
$ ldapsearch -v -x -H ldaps://127.0.0.1:636/ -b dc=org
ldap_initialize( ldaps://127.0.0.1:636/??base )
filter: (objectclass=*)
requesting: All userApplication attributes
# extended LDIF
#
# LDAPv3
# base <dc=org> with scope subtree
# filter: (objectclass=*)
# requesting: ALL
#

# search result
search: 2
result: 32 No such object

# numResponses: 1
```

haproxy is similar; you must set `mode tcp` and create a `listen` block (or matching `frontend` and `backend` blocks) that terminates SSL/TLS from the client and originates it to the server. One minor difference is that haproxy *requires* the cert and key to be in a single file (nginx, and apache httpd, have this as an *option*). The packaged config on my Ubuntu used `option httplog` which isn't valid for mode tcp so I also changed that.

```
listen x
        bind :636 ssl crt /home/dthomps/certs-loc3-combined-temp.pem
        server y db.debian.org:636 ssl verify required ca-file ca-certificates.crt verifyhost db.debian.org
# the Ubuntu package has ca-base configured so that ca-file expands to the correct one
```